# Running my camper on solar

Tags: electrical

I would lIke to run my camper fully on solar and I'm unsure what I would need to do it right. It would be for heavy use, lights, appliances, tv, ect... I have a 2014 camper that has a 50 amp plug on it. Does anyone feel like walking me through this? Thanx

Comment: You really should take the time to create a profile of your power usage.  Which devices require the most power and how long do they run for?  Which devices don't consume much power but run for long periods of time?  In other words, define your peak power requirements as well as the average power used.  Only then can anyone offer suggestions.

Comment: Do a google search for "boondocking" This question as is is too broad to answer. Once you do a little research you'll better know what question to ask.

Comment: Also running what you currently have completely on solar is going to be cost, space, and weight prohibitive.

Comment: I also see you are new to these sites. Please take the [tour] and read [ask] to help you edit this into a question better suited to the SE sites. This has the potential to be a great question, but it's going to take a little work.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you'll need is BIG trailer to hold the solar cells. So let's try for a first cut at the numbers.

If you really must produce 120 volts at 50 amps, that's 6000 watts. The question is, how long do you need this load each day, or its equivalent? After all, you won't be going full out all the time. Let's say that your average load is 1000 watts for 12 hours per day.

So, 1000 watts times 12 hours is 12 kwh. Most of this energy is going to come from your batteries which the solar cells charge, since obviously the sun goes down each day. As a rough rule of thumb, figure on 50% efficiency in going from cells to load. The battery does not store all the energy it receives, and you need to drive an inverter to go from battery DC to appliance AC. So the solar cells will need to produce about 24 kWh per day.

The sun is not very bright at the horizon, so you can figure on (at most) about 6 hours per day of useful output from the solar array, and to get this you'll need a tracking array to keep the cells perpendicular to the sun. So your 24 kWh has to be produced in 6 hours, for a load of 4 kW. (4 kW x 6 hours is 24 kW).

In clear air, assume sunlight is about 1 kw per square meter, but solar cells are only (at best) about 20% efficient, so your array needs to intercept 20 kW of sunlight (4 kW / 0.2), and this will take about 20 square meters, or about 200 square feet.

As I say, you'll need a big trailer. Plus, of course, your mobile home cannot be moving during peak charging time.

And finally, the above is based on the sun being available every day. So how much bad weather can you tolerate? If you're willing to tolerate 2 days of rain, you need 3 times as much solar capacity, or 600 square feet of cells.

And the batteries are going to be big and heavy (another reason for a big trailer), but that's another story.

If you can't afford the very best cells, you'll need more of them, too.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really even start until you know how much power you will use.  Having a 50 amp plug means that you have the potential to use a lot of power, but that doesn't mean that you will use that much.

For example, the first answer suggests the number of panels required is more than I have seen in many whole home systems!  Maybe you need that much maybe not.

If you can get a 'kill-a-watt' meter or something similar which measures the amount of energy you use that would be the first step  if not, then look at all of your devices and appliances and find out how much power they consume (it will say on them) then consider how long you would use each appliance every day and then you have a rough estimate of power needed.

From there you can begin to consider what you need in terms of solar panels, which isn't too hard.  When solar experts assess a place for solar requirements, they usually recommend to have enough battery for 3 days use.  This is for those winter months when the sun isn't seen for days, or for rain in the summer.

When you know how much power you need in watts, you can source solar panels since they are rated in watts.  In addition you will need a charge controller for the batteries and an inverter to convert the battery power to AC.

But solar installation companies always start with how much power to you use?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the 50 amp plug is 220VAC. You probably wont be able to generate that much electricity with solar, as you would need A LOT of panels to get that amount of energy. However you could supply supplenental energy, or recharge any 12v battery packs.

To do this you would need solar panels, and an inverter (charging controller). You can buy solar panel kits for your RV. I would suggest that you do this, because mixing and matching solar panel parts can be a daunting task, and is not easy to get right.

Googling "solar panel kit" should get you some products that will work to fill your need.

Answer (score 0):

Run *fully* on solar? No chance!

There are any number of solar kits on the market that will connect to your leisure battery within the camper.  They aren't difficult to install.  Just follow the instructions.